# How to label each node in a dendrogram based on label for the children using R

Tags: r, dendrogram, hierarchical-clustering

I have a dendrogram in R where each leaf has a value. I like to define each node's value by summing the value of its children. I am familiar with dendrapply, however I don't know how to access a node's child in the function and how to write the function recursively.

here is the code to begin with:

```
library("stats")
library("fastcluster")
library("cluster")
D = rbind( + c(1,1,1,1,1), 
 + c(1,2,1,1,1),
 + c(2,2,2,2,2), 
 + c(3,4,5,6,9)

)
dnd = as.dendrogram(hclust.vector(D))

apply_text <<- function(n) {
   if (!is.leaf(n)) {

      attr(n, "edgetext") <- add the value of the branches
   }
   if (is.leaf(n)) {
      attr(n, "edgetext") <- 1
   }
   n
}

tmp <- dendrapply(dnd, apply_text)
plot(tmp)
```

Comment: You should add what code you are using right now, or what part's of the required code you know. That will make it easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: I think you are asking for two things: 1) to add information to the dendrogram. 2) to have that information show in a figure. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

This may be an answer, however, it is reimplementing the dendrapply.

```
apply_text <<- function(n){
  if (!is.leaf(n)) {
    cutversion = cut(n, h = attributes(n)$height)
    leftLabel = attr(apply_text(cutversion$lower[[1]]), "edgetext")  
    rightLabel= attr(apply_text(cutversion$lower[[2]]), "edgetext")
    attr(n, "edgetext") = as.numeric(as.character(leftLabel)) + as.numeric(as.character(rightLabel)) 
     }
  if(is.leaf(n)) {
    attr(n,"edgetext") <- 1
  }
    n
}

tmp <- dendrapply(dnd, apply_text)
```

Does anybody have a clue how to remove the polygon on the labels? Somebody else also seems to have asked for them to be removed. Any progress on that?

Comment: Why don't you replace tmp <- dendrapply(dnd, apply_text) by apply_text(dnd) or something like this?

Comment: I tried to apply apply_text on the tree but only the root and the leaves are labeled and the intermediary ones are not. Most likely there is a problem with the way I am returning the subtrees. dendrapply sweeps the tree node by node and it ends up having all nodes labeled. I think I am missing something here because I am somehow doing what dendrapply is supposed to do recursively.